# More about property releasing

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, properties

Maybe someone could explain the difference between property:

in .h file

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *someString;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *someString2;
```

in .m file

```
@synthesize someString = _someString;
```

or

```
@synthesize someString2;
```

what is the difference for _someString and self.someString2 using in controller?
 and in dealloc how i should release these property's

```
[_someString release];
```

AND

```
[self.someString2 release];
```

OR

```
_someString = nil;
_someString2 = nil;
```

Comment: How did appear _someString2 here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After:

```
property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *someString;
property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *someString2;
```

and:

```
@synthesize someString = _someString;
@synthesize someString2;
```

`someString` is a property backed by the instance variable `_someString`. Memory retention and release is managed by Obj-C.

- Assignments to `someString` should use the form `self.someString` within the class, and must use `<reference>.someString` outside of it. Except within an initializer there should never be **any** assignments to a plain `_someString`.
- Reading the value can use simply `_someString` within the class, but `self.someString` is also valid, and  must use `<reference>.someString` outside of it.
- Releasing the value must use the form `self.someString = nil` within the class, and `<reference>.someString = nil` outside of it.

`someString2` is similar except it is backed by an automatically named instance variable, which happens to be called `someString2`.

Answer (score 5):

```
synthesize someString = _someString;
```

This says synthesize the property `someString` but for direct access, use `_somestring`.

```
synthesize someString2;
```

This says synthesize the property `someString2` but for direct access, use `someString2`.

Think of it as if the compiler is generating the iVars for you but in the first case the iVar is called `_someString` and the second is called `someString2`

This is a common usage (I recently moved to it) so that when you are dealing with the object directly (such as initialisers or in `dealloc`, where you should't use `self`) you can see instantly that when you write `_someString = @"aString";` you are not going through the property methods that would apply the memory management types (such as retain, or copy). It used to be common that people would assign values directly, and then wonder why they weren't being retained.

```
[_someString release];
[_someString2 release];
```

Is sending the release method directly to the object.

```
self.someString = nil;
self.someString2 = nil;
```

Sends release through the property. In this case, There is no difference. There would be a difference if you were allocating objects: for example:

```
_someString = someOtherString;
```

Is a leak (except under ARC, which I will come to later), because you are just putting in a new object to the store, without releasing the current object.

```
self.someString = someOtherString;
```

does not leak anything, because the sythesized setter will release the current object before setting (and retaining) the new object.

I said I'd come to ARC. In which case you can't call `release` anyway, so the questions don't arise, but `_someString = someOtherString` is not a leak, because the compiler will deal with releasing the current object for you.

Answer (score 1):

@synthesize someString = _someString; Means you're making a property with a different name then the member variable it's associated with. This is fine. Typically they are same name. Here's an example when that isn't the case. So someString would be your property and _someString is your member variable.

As for [_someString release]; and [self.someString2 release]; what you're seeing is release being called on the member variable of your class(Which is _someString). [self.someString2 release] calls release on whatever the property returns. Keep in mind that properties can do more then just simply get and set. They are methods just like any other you might right.

Also, don't do [self.someString2 release]; Instead do self.someString2 = nil; That will release it on your behalf. That way it nils out the string. That will protect you from accessing bad memory incase the string is actually deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

`_someString = nil` won't release your property.

In this case `_someString` and `self._someString` point to the exact same object, so you can release using either.

Comment: it's not recommended, however, to release the property getter! Like  [self.someString release] may be incorrect! (the compiler can generate autorelease getters, so that's a bad practice!)

Answer (score 0):

```
[_someString release];
```

AND

```
[self.someString2 release];
```

releases twice, that's wrong. Use

```
_someString = nil;
_someString2 = nil;
```

simply sets your ivars to nil, it doesn't release them, so that's again wrong.

Correct: either

```
self.someString = nil;
self.someString2 = nil;
```

or

```
[_someString release];
[_someString2 release];
```

I'd recommend the first one (dot-notation), as it does the right thing (you don't know what kind of code does a compiler generate when synthesizing your accessors...)